Flutter Build Release APK: Failed - Execution failed for task ':facebook_audience_network:verifyReleaseResources'
flutter build apk --release is unable to build release apk of my Flutter application. It is giving the error for facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1 plugin which is declared in pubspec.yaml file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
